TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'list' and 'int' in pokerenv
I am trying to use the pokerenv library for a reinforcement learning project, but even the example code provided by the documentation itself produces the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 13
     11 while True:
     12     action = agents[acting_player].get_action(obs)
---> 13     print(f"acion{table.step(action)} tipo{table.step(action)}")
     14     obs, reward, done, _ = table.step(action)
     15     print(f"obs={obs} tipo{type(obs)}")

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pokerenv/table.py:199, in Table.step(self, action)
    196                 self.next_player_i = min(active_players_before)
    198 if self.street_finished and not self.hand_is_over:
--> 199     self._street_transition()
    201 obs = np.zeros(self.observation_space.shape[0]) if self.hand_is_over else self._get_observation(self.players[self.next_player_i])
    202 rewards = np.asarray([player.get_reward() for player in sorted(self.players)])

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pokerenv/table.py:219, in Table._street_transition(self, transition_to_end)
    215 new = self.deck.draw(1)
    216 self.cards.append(new)
    217 self._write_event("*** TURN *** [%s %s %s] [%s]" %
    218                   (Card.int_to_str(self.cards[0]), Card.int_to_str(self.cards[1]),
--> 219                    Card.int_to_str(self.cards[2]), Card.int_to_str(self.cards[3])))
    220 self.street = GameState.TURN
    221 transitioned = True

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/treys/card.py:81, in Card.int_to_str(card_int)
     79 @staticmethod
     80 def int_to_str(card_int: int) -> str:
---> 81     rank_int = Card.get_rank_int(card_int)
     82     suit_int = Card.get_suit_int(card_int)
     83     return Card.STR_RANKS[rank_int] + Card.INT_SUIT_TO_CHAR_SUIT[suit_int]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/treys/card.py:87, in Card.get_rank_int(card_int)
     85 @staticmethod
     86 def get_rank_int(card_int: int) -> int:
---> 87     return (card_int >> 8) & 0xF

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'list' and 'int'

This is the minimal required code, and all dependencies are in the latest version.
import numpy as np
import pokerenv.obs_indices as indices
from pokerenv.table import Table
from pokerenv.common import PlayerAction, Action, action_list


class ExampleRandomAgent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.actions = []
        self.observations = []
        self.rewards = []

    def get_action(self, observation):
        self.observations.append(observation)
        valid_actions = np.argwhere(observation[indices.VALID_ACTIONS] == 1).flatten()
        valid_bet_low = observation[indices.VALID_BET_LOW]
        valid_bet_high = observation[indices.VALID_BET_HIGH]
        chosen_action = PlayerAction(np.random.choice(valid_actions))
        bet_size = 0
        if chosen_action is PlayerAction.BET:
            bet_size = np.random.uniform(valid_bet_low, valid_bet_high)
        table_action = Action(chosen_action, bet_size)
        self.actions.append(table_action)
        return table_action

    def reset(self):
        self.actions = []
        self.observations = []
        self.rewards = []

active_players = 6
agents = [ExampleRandomAgent() for _ in range(6)]
player_names = {0: 'TrackedAgent1', 1: 'Agent2'} # Rest are defaulted to player3, player4...
# Should we only log the 0th players (here TrackedAgent1) private cards to hand history files
track_single_player = True 
# Bounds for randomizing player stack sizes in reset()
low_stack_bbs = 50
high_stack_bbs = 200
hand_history_location = 'hands/'
invalid_action_penalty = 0
table = Table(active_players, 
              player_names=player_names,
              track_single_player=track_single_player,
              stack_low=low_stack_bbs,
              stack_high=high_stack_bbs,
              hand_history_location=hand_history_location,
              invalid_action_penalty=invalid_action_penalty
)
table.seed(1)

iteration = 1
while True:
    if iteration % 50 == 0:
        table.hand_history_enabled = True
    active_players = np.random.randint(2, 7)
    table.n_players = active_players
    obs = table.reset()
    for agent in agents:
        agent.reset()
    acting_player = int(obs[indices.ACTING_PLAYER])
    while True:
        action = agents[acting_player].get_action(obs)
        obs, reward, done, _ = table.step(action)
        #print(f"obs={obs} tipo{type(obs)}")
        #print(f"reward={reward} tipo{type(reward)}")
        #print(f"done={done} tipo{type(done)}")
        if  done:
            # Distribute final rewards
            for i in range(active_players):
                agents[i].rewards.append(reward[i])
            break
        else:
            # This step can be skipped unless invalid action penalty is enabled, 
            # since we only get a reward when the pot is distributed, and the done flag is set
            agents[acting_player].rewards.append(reward[acting_player])
            acting_player = int(obs[indices.ACTING_PLAYER])
    iteration += 1
    table.hand_history_enabled = False

The code is an exact copy of the example given in the documentation (https://pypi.org/project/pokerenv/). Additionally, the error does not occur immediately but after the first 13 steps of the environment, so it seems that the process fails at step 14 or later. Generally, the failure occurs at that step, but I have seen it happen at step 10 or go up to step 20 before the error occurs. Since it is related to the action and it is random, could it be an issue with the actor?
Additionally, looking at the library's code, the card variable is initialized as a list, specifically as self.card = [] in the function that initiates the environment. Apparently, this variable is only overwritten or modified as needed in each function.

To address this error, modify the Card.get_rank_int method. Instead of performing a right bit-shift on a list, ensure that you're using an integer.
This can be caused by the versions of libraries you are using to run your code.
Deck.draw is (integer) and not a list.
